# tinyMCE and referring tinyMCE from CDN networks shows distorted icons

Tags: angular, tinymce

I am trying to use tinyMCE as given in below project

```
[http://plnkr.co/edit/E5Yzk9KT9nSWlPU6i1ZK?p=preview][1]
```

Provided above project it uses CDN link for referring tinymce.min.js file, I have incorporated same thing in my project, however it shows distored incons in my project. (please see attached screenshot )

I am trying to use tinyMCE without API keys or cloud version. Please help if you have implemented same thing.

Shall I download tinymce.min.js from the site and have it in my project asset folder ? please assist.

[image: attached is screenshot of how it looks like]

I tried to put tinyMCE.min.js into asset folder of the app and referring it angular.json under scripts tag , but it does not display anything on the page, however if I put CDN link under index.html it does work. I dont know why but if someone can help me please.

Answer (score 0):

TinyMCE is comprised of far more than just one JS file so if that is the only thing you have copied you are missing many of the files needed for TinyMCE to run properly.

The process for downloading/setting up a self hosted TinyMCE installation can be found here:

https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/general-configuration-guide/advanced-install/#sdkinstall